# Can I convert 72V to 12V using potential divider?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, voltage-divider, buck

In our automation project, we'll be using a buck converter to convert the DC voltage from 72V to 12V. This method of conversion is quite expensive!! We are converting the voltage to power the raspberry pi 3 B+ and some sensors. So first, we need to charge our power bank through a car charger.

I was thinking if we can use a potential divider circuit for this purpose or a cheaper way?

What are the drawbacks of doing this?

*it seems like not possible or having critical drawback :)*

Comment: Please edit your question to state how much current you require at 12 V. Have you worked out the power loss in the potential divider? If so please add your calculations into the question too.

Comment: I'm not sure about the power and current requirement... we've been given less information about this :(

Comment: Voltage dividers are in general not suitable for supplying the desired voltage as the output depends on the load current. And yes, they "waste" power. It is mostly used for signals where insignificant current only is expected.

Comment: @Ashdeep: Well give some estimate. Otherwise your question can't be answered well. Is it a few mA to light an LED or is it 20 A to drive a motor? Again, put the information in the question.

Comment: This is almost certainly a bad idea.  Even a *controlled* voltage divider (which is sold under the label of "Linear Voltage Regulator") would waste five times as much power as heat, as it delivered to the load.   At such high difference ratios, switching regulation is really the only viable DC/DC approach for anything above miniscule currents.

Comment: The current into a divider has to be more than, or (at best) exactly equal to the current used by the load -- and that's a rather absurd "at best", because you'd have essentially no load regulation.  In your case, the power in is 72V * current, while the power out is 12V * current.  So **at best** you would burn up five times as much power as you use.   But that would require a "divider" that's just a dropping resistor, which is totally unsuitable.

Comment: Related: [Powering Arduino from a voltage divider](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/223731/6334)

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if buck converting the voltage multiple times can provide for a good solution (I've never tried it.)

Comment: if u feel cost of IC are costly. try for discrete implementation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essense: **no.**

You will need to use very large resistor values, elsewise the current draw from the 72V source and heat dissipation on the voltage divider will be too large. By making a potential divider with huge resistor values, you make a power supply with a ridiculous output resistance, since the output resistance of a potential divider is equal to R1*R2/(R1+R2), where R1 and R2 are the resistor values in the potential divider.

Let's try to design a potential divider for your case. The current drawn by the potential divider itself will be 72V/(R1+R2), while the heat dissipation will be (72V)^2 / (R1+R2). 1W power losses is already very bad, but let's stay with that value for reduced complexity. From (72V)^2 / (R1+R2) = 1W we see that R1+R2 = 5184 ohm. Since you need 12V output, R2/(R1+R2) = 12/72. From there two equations we get that R1 = 4320 Ohm, R2 = 864 Ohm and the output resistance R1*R2/(R1+R2) = 720 Ohm.

720Ohm output resistance means that this potential divider PSU could handle no more than 12V/720Ohm current, which is equal to 16mA. This is way too low for the Pi to even turn on. Furthermore, any current ripple will kill the power from the Raspberry Pi, since the voltage ripple will be equal to 720 Ohm * current ripple.

You may try to increase the power dissipation. Then, for example, for 0.5A current draw you can reverse-solve the equations I gave before and get a power dissipation of (72V - 12V) * 0.5A = 30W.

Even a linear regulator won't suite you here, since 60V drop is just humongous (I think I've never even seen one that could handle such a high voltage). The power dissipation (and loss) will be the same: (72V-12V)*0.5A = 30W.

So, you **need** to use a DC-DC converter. And they cost a lot because handling 72V is no easy task in power electronics.

Answer (score 1):

In general voltage dividers are a poor choice for power supplies because to acheive a stable output voltage over varying load the current wasted in the divider must be much greater than the current delievered to the load.

I would generally recommend an isolated converter unless you know exactly what you are doing, sharing return paths between high power high voltage systems and low voltage systems can be a recipie for trouble.

Unfortunately 72V DC puts you in an awkward place, it's too high for most common DC-DC modules, but too low for mains power supplies. So converters are going to be specialised and hence expensive.

Comment: any alternatives for this as I need to charge the power bank somehow! I've edited the question... and briefed how we're doing this process!

Comment: You know the alternative. You just don't want to pay for it.

Comment: Actually I wouldn't recommend a buck converter either. I would reccomend an isolated DC-DC.

Answer (score 1):

A voltage divider would be a really bad choice here.  The Raspberry Pi, at worst case, requires about 1.8A.  To provide 1.8A to the Pi through resistors, you would have to dissipate at least P = IV = (72V-12V)*(1.8A) = 108W!  (Roughly twice the power of a good soldering iron!)